# Why InvokeVirtual used instead of InvokeSpecial when calling class.NewInstance()?

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm, jvm-hotspot

I was looking into the disassembly of the following java program

```
public class ASMPlayground {
    private String bar;

    public String getBar(){
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        String name = String.class.newInstance();
        System.out.println(name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

The following bytecode snippet caught my eye and seemed sub-optimal

```
LDC Ljava/lang/String;.class
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Class.newInstance ()Ljava/lang/Object;
CHECKCAST java/lang/String
```

**Question:**

InvokeVirtual is used when the method to be executed is dependent on the object reference. Given that "Class" is final and newInstance() exists only 
in the "Class" why not use InvokeSpecial instead of InvokeVirtual ? Wouldn't it be more performant?

Answer (score 3):

`InvokeSpecial` is used to designate invocations that are

> superclass, private, and instance initialization method invocations

Spec: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokespecial

`Class.newInstance` is neither superclass method call nor private method call nor call to initialization method. It also isn't a dynamic method, `InvokeDynamic` has nothing to do here. Both instructions cannot be used here because it would confront jvms. At the time of creating jvms it was possible to allow substitute of some instructions with "more performant" ones, but as I see in jvms it hasn't been done.

> Wouldn't it be more performant?

JIT is smart enough to understand that there's no need to traverse virtual method table in such cases, so it shouldn't slow execution down. Actual performance should be compared by actual tests, but I see no reasons to expect significant difference there.

Comment: In particular `Class` is `final` so the only virtual methods are calls to parent class methods.

Comment: I have made an edit. InvokedDynamic was a typo. I meant to say InvokeVirtual.

Comment: I did check out the documentation of InvokeSpecial. I also checked for InvokeVirtual

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual
Invoke instance method; dispatch based on class

Still not able to understand why invokevirtual is used here given class is final. 

Could answer could be that InvokedSpecial opcode could work only for methods of the same/super class.

Comment: `InvokeVirtual` is used for all virtual methods. `javac` doesn't do all the analysis it could do. I suppose it just doesn't use information about class `final` modifier at method call instruction compilation. And yes, `InvokeSpecial` is designed for only a limited set of methods.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that a target method or class is `final` does never change the compiled form a class using the other class/calling the method.

This is mandated by the JLS, Chapter 13. “Binary Compatibility”, [§13.4.17, `final` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.17):

> Changing a method that is declared `final` to no longer be declared `final` does not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries.

Likewise [§13.4.2. `final` Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.2)

> Changing a class that is declared `final` to no longer be declared `final` does not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries.

Obviously, an invocation instruction relying on the target method’s `final` nature would violate this specification.

There is no relevant performance impact to expect. There is always a first time overhead, when the symbolic reference has to be resolved to the actual method (in terms of the JVM’s runtime representation). Right at this point, the JVM can also record the fact that this method or its declaring class is actually `final` to the invocation instruction, if there is a benefit. Modern JVMs go even farther and, e.g. utilize the fact that a non-`final` method has not been actually overridden to the same effect, though these invocations would need to be deoptimized if a subclass gets loaded and instantiated, which has an overriding method. So the only difference is that a `final` modifier guarantees that such deoptimization will never be necessary.

Comment: Does `final` really guarantee anything? Modifier can be removed at runtime and fake sources can be substituted during compilation, class loading is lazy so I thought it should be allowed. Do you have any link stating otherwise?

Comment: @Sergey Fedorov: well, as the first part of my answer explains, before the class has been loaded, `final` has no impact at all, as demanded by the *Binary Compatibility* specification. The last sentence of my answer is relevant to the JVM only after the class has been loaded and the JVM started optimizing based on the assumption that the method will never be overridden. Then, the JVM will reject override attempts, if the method is `final`. However, this is still JVM implementation specific. E.g. if a JVM allows removing `final` via Instrumentation, it must support deoptimizing in that case.

Comment: afaik, hotspot jit does support deoptimization, but that's not the point. Modifier can be removed with just reflection, that isn't jvm-specific and at least works with fields. Until now I thought it should work with methods too so actually `final` means nothing after compilation finishes. Do you know any evidence that can disprove this?

Comment: @Sergey Fedorov: There seem to be a lot of myths spreading around regarding what you can do with “just reflection”. Reflection is a read-only facility, which caches some data. You can manipulate these privately cached data via access override (how can that not be implementation specific?), but that only affects what Reflection will subsequently report (until the cached information is purged). Do you really believe, the JVM asks Reflection about the modifiers when loading a class? Show me “any evidence that can prove this”…